# For the US Population dataset built in to Tidyverse, how do I get the "19 values" (age, race, population, state, etc.) to display?

Tags: r, data-analysis

Whenever I `?usop' it tells me there are 19 values, but I want to see what all 19 of those values are.

I'm watching [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPJn1CMvtmI&list=PLtL57Fdbwb_C6RS0JtBojTNOMVlgpeJkS&ab_channel=RProgramming101) but they are only using a dataset with two variables. I found it too easy, so I wanted to step up the difficulty.

Comment: Is `usop` a typo, and you mean `datasets::uspop`? If yes, It's a time series, basically a single vector of length 19 with few extra attributes; executing `uspop`  prints all there is to print. If no, please include the package name of the dataset, `tidyverse` package itself does not include any of those.